# Convert a C or numpy array to a Tkinter PhotoImage with a minimum number of copies

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I know a recipe for displaying an MxNx3 numpy array as an RGB image via Tkinter, but my recipe makes several copies of the array in the process:

```
a = np.random.randint(low=255, size=(100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # Original
ppm_header = b'P6\n%i %i\n255\n'%(a.shape[0], a.shape[1])
a_bytes = a.tobytes() # First copy
ppm_bytes = ppm_header + a_bytes # Second copy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format
root = tk.Tk()
img = tk.PhotoImage(data=ppm_bytes) # Third and fourth copies?
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=a.shape[0], height=a.shape[1])
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=img) # Fifth copy?
root.mainloop()
```

**How can I achieve an equivalent result with a minimum number of copies?**

Ideally, I would create a numpy array which was a view of the same bytes that the Tkinter `PhotoImage` object was using, effectively giving me a `PhotoImage` with mutable pixel values, and making it cheap and fast to update the Tkinter display. I don't know how to extract this pointer from Tkinter.

Perhaps there's a way via ctypes, as [hinted at here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4u0xh8/fastest_way_to_share_numpy_arrays_between/d5n4e1p)?

The `PhotoImage.put()` method seems very slow, but maybe I'm wrong, and that's a path forward?

I tried making a `bytearray()` containing the ppm header and the image pixel values, and then using `numpy.frombuffer()` to view the image pixel values as a numpy array, but I think the `PhotoImage` constructor wants a `bytes()` object, not a `bytearray()` object, and also I think Tkinter copies the bytes of its `data` input into its internal format (32-bit RGBA?). I guess this saves me one copy compared to the recipe above?

Comment: FWIW, the underlying data storage of the Tk photo image is RGBA, with 8 bits per pixel per channel. The maximally efficient approach is definitely going to involve starting with that, though I don't know how to actually make that work in Tkinter…

Comment: @donal-fellows I have some experience using ctypes to talk to C dlls, but I don't know enough about how tkinter is implemented to get started. Is there something like a tkinter shared library with a documented API that Python makes calls to?

Comment: The underlying library API is [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkLib/contents.htm), and the API call you need is `Tk_PhotoPutBlock()` ([here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkLib/FindPhoto.htm)). Assembling the arguments for it… well, that's a bit trickier. The _handle_ can be got from `Tk_FindPhoto()`, but the _interp_ is buried inside Tkinter (the Python-to-Tcl/Tk wrapping library) and I don't know that well enough to help. Also, you **MUST** use that code from only one thread or you get major trouble (a common Python/Tkinter issue).

Answer (score 5):

I can reduce it to 1 (maybe 2) copies by using PIL and a Label:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

a = np.random.randint(low=255, size=(100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # Original
root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(a)) # First and maybe second copy.
lbl = tk.Label(root, image=img)
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However that's still not mutable. If you want that I think you need to reinvent an image by placing a pixel on the canvas yourself. I did that once with [this project](https://github.com/novel-yet-trivial/re-place) and found that the fastest update was a matplotlib animation, which works really well for you since you are already using np arrays.

My code for using a [tk.Canvas](https://github.com/novel-yet-trivial/re-place/blob/tkcanvas/re-place.py), a [PIL Image](https://github.com/novel-yet-trivial/re-place/blob/pilimage/re-place.py)(using putpixel()), and [matplotlib](https://github.com/novel-yet-trivial/re-place/blob/master/re-place.py).

Comment: You actually only saved one copy compared to the original code: `a_bytes = a.tobytes(); ppm_bytes = ppm_header + a_bytes` -> `Image.fromarray(a)`.

Comment: `ImageTk.PhotoImage` involves two copies: it [delegates to `tkinter.BitmapImage`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/e9221cf84fd2074c3f0f85f3932bf3bcee6ac92f/src/PIL/ImageTk.py) which [involves two copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459277/convert-a-c-or-numpy-array-to-a-tkinter-photoimage-with-a-minimum-number-of-copi/52494356#52494356).

Answer (score 3):

- **you can eliminate the 1st and 2nd copies**

You get a `numpy.ndarray` over arbitrary data with [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html):

```
shape=(100,100,3)
ppm_header = b'P6\n%i %i\n255\n'%(shape[0], shape[1])
ppm_bytes = ppm_header + b'\0'*(shape[0]*shape[1]*shape[2])
array_image = np.frombuffer(ppm_bytes, dtype=np.uint8, offset=len(ppm_header)).reshape(shape)
```

- **the 3rd and 4th copies are inevitable** (see below), but the 3rd one is discarded right after the call
- **the 5th copy is not actually made** (also see below)
- **the drawing stage involves a copy to the screen via the windowing system's drawing API** which is also inevitable.

---

Tcl is a safe, garbage-collected language like Python, and Tcl objects don't support either a "buffer protocol", or using memory for their data that they don't own (though objects can be shared.

- > ```
  > img = tk.PhotoImage(data=ppm_bytes) # Third and fourth copies?
  > ```

  [When making most Tcl calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c#L1452), Python variables are first [converted into Equivalent Tcl objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c#L1318) (first into C values [which doesn't involve copying for a bytestring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/bytesobject.h#L87) which are then passed to Tcl constructors [which does involve a copy](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/c956247a9b291ef841accb8e7a86fb5904f76a85/generic/tclBinary.c#L315)), then these objects are passed to `Tcl_EvalObjv`.

  On the Tcl side, [`photo`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/photo.htm) (which `PhotoImage()` wraps) also *parses* input data (`-data` string argument) and as such, also cannot reuse its memory block. [Even if it's a raw bitmap](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/generic/tkImgBmap.c#L532) 'cuz Tcl strings have no "view" functionality.

  So, for a bytestring, there's one mandatory copy of the bitmap data involved at Pythob-to-Tcl call stage, and one more at image construction stage. (On the bright side, one copy (the argument string for the Tcl call) is discarded after the call.)
- > ```
  > canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=img) # Fifth copy?
  > ```

  A copy is not involved here, [the canvas just saves a reference to the image object in its composition data](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/generic/tkCanvImg.c#L319).

  Now, [`canvas create image` requires a Tcl image identifier as `image` argument](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M139); so there's no way around `PhotoImage()`, either.
- **(drawing stage)**

  [`xlib`'s commands to draw a bitmap are used](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/generic/tkImgPhInstance.c#L630), no additional copies are involved.

  The thing to note here is that a canvas doesn't even *have* direct access to the resulting screen pixels. Instead, `xlib` uses backend's graphical API for drawing (like WinGDI's `GetDC()`, `BitBlt()` etc that you might be familiar with). E.g. [in Windows, `xlib`'s `XCopyArea` uses `BitBlt`](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/win/tkWinDraw.c#L300).

Comment: I think what he's looking for is a way to pass his binary blob to the C API call; numpy can certainly generate the right format of data. That'll let the copies that are done at least be a straight `memcpy()` under the hood.

Comment: @DonalFellows [Tk C API](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkLib/contents.htm) is unavailable from Tkinter. Moreover, `photo create` is implemented with [`tkImgPhoto.c:ImgPhotoCreate`](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/generic/tkImgPhoto.c#L124) which isn't even exposed in the API.

Comment: Yes. This is why this is an expert-level need for work. However, if you can get the handle name (a small string) then you should be able to do the rest with a fairly small chunk of C code. It'd probably be a bit of a hack under the covers as it is bridging two thoroughly-different memory management schemes (Python and Tcl), but it could be made to work and would be actually fast.

Comment: @DonalFellows It won't be just a "hack", it will be tremendously fragile. Since Tcl's objects don't support either a "buffer protocol", or using memory for their data that they don't own. You _can_ get to the data buffer by parsing the memory -- in Tcl/Tk version-, architecture-, compiler- and compilation options-specific way, -- forge that buffer's data -- in likewise way -- and even then that buffer can be moved or discarded at any moment. So as an expert, I cannot recommend this venue.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I implemented a "ripple tank" simulator in numpy+TkInter that I believe to be quite optimized in terms of speed. It is freely available here:

https://gist.github.com/FilipDominec/14761052f42d80d283bd3adcf7eb5347