# How to open the cv2 window inside a tkinter window

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I found on the internet [this python code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEcBnD80nLg) for counting people with the Open CV library. I would need to open the window that opens with CV2, inside a Tkinter window in order to then add the commands for the settings.

This is the code from GitHub: https://github.com/Gupu25/PeopleCounter

How can I make the two OpenCv windows open inside a Tkinter window?

Comment: You probably need to convert the `NumPy` array (OpenCV's image object in Python) to tkinter's image object (`PhotoImage`), then display this image on a tkinter window. You can convert `PIL` images into `PhotoImage`s, so a possible conversion chain would be from  `NumPy` array to  `PIL` to  `PhotoImage`. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459277/convert-a-c-or-numpy-array-to-a-tkinter-photoimage-with-a-minimum-number-of-copi

Comment: "open inside of" is not possible because OpenCV's `imshow` is its own GUI thing. -- you *can* show the data/image/array instead in Tkinter itself, as described above.

Comment: I had previously tried to insert an additional tkinter window with buttons but as long as the tkinter window remained open, the video to count the cars did not start. can you make it open a tkinter window for settings and in the background let CV2 windows run?

Comment: nope. only one GUI event loop runs at a time. do not try to run tkinter and imshow at the same time. instead, listen to @stateMachine, use a tkinter label, construct a PhotoImage from the numpy array, and stick it in the label.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of opening a video in a tkinter window with OpenCV's VideoCapture object:

```
from tkinter import NW, Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage
import cv2 

def photo_image(img):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    data = f'P6 {w} {h} 255 '.encode() + img[..., ::-1].tobytes()
    return PhotoImage(width=w, height=h, data=data, format='PPM')

def update():
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret:
        photo = photo_image(img)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=NW)
        canvas.image = photo
    root.after(15, update)

root = Tk()
root.title("Video")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1200, height=700)
canvas.pack()
update()
root.mainloop()
cap.release()
```

To display 2 OpenCV videos, simply make a few adjustments, and use the [`np.hstack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) method or the [`np.vstack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) method, depending on whether you want your videos to be displayed side by side horizontally or vertically:

```
from tkinter import NW, Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage
import cv2 
import numpy as np

def photo_image(img):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    data = f'P6 {w} {h} 255 '.encode() + img[..., ::-1].tobytes()
    return PhotoImage(width=w, height=h, data=data, format='PPM')

def update():
    ret1, img1 = cap1.read()
    ret2, img2 = cap2.read()
    if ret1:
        photo = photo_image(np.hstack((img1, img2)))
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=NW)
        canvas.image = photo
    root.after(15, update)

root = Tk()
root.title("Video")
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture("video1.mp4")
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture("video2.mp4")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1200, height=700)
canvas.pack()
update()
root.mainloop()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Does video displayed in a tkinter GUI always run slow? I've seen quite a few examples and none playback at full speed.